# Display counter of records in dynamic text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have dynamic text field which allow user to add/remove. First, the field will display records from the database.

```
$count = 1;
foreach($parts as $part)
{               
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"countNumber\" value=\"".$count."\">";
    echo $count++;
}
```

And this is my jQuery dynamic text field. 
**JSFIDDLE**: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/20/)

I need to increment my number once user clicked `+`. For example, if my database consists of 5 records, then the count will be `1,2,3,4,5`, then once user clicked on the dynamic text field add button, the number will continue from previous count and it will become `6,7,8...`. Again, if user clicked on `-` button, the count will be reorder again.

But I have no idea how to do that. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: Your example is already doing what you say you want....?

Comment: I don't see a question. I see a description of what you want/need to do, but nothing to state what you are having an issue with.

Comment: Are you trying to keep track of database row ID using count or is count only for visual purposes ?

Comment: @Kisaragi , the example not the exactly what I want. First, the php code will increment but when I clicked on + button, the jQuery will detect and continue the latest number of count. But I'm not sure how to do it. And the number will reorder again when I clicked on - button.

Comment: From the JSFIDDLE above, it only shows the number starting with `1` but still not yet get the latest value of my `$count` of my php code

Comment: Are you trying to pass the $count of your PHP code to the count javascript variable? <? echo "<script>var count = $count;</script>" ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use classes and redefine the index using a recount function when `.remove` is clicked. this will reorder the input ids starting from 1 again (so if you have 1,2,3,4,5 and you remove 3, all the fields will be reordered as 1,2,3,4 and the next time you press +, you will be adding 5.)

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/23/

```
function reorder() {
    var reCount = 1;
    $('.field').each(function() {
        elem = $(this);
        elem.attr('id', 'field' + reCount);
        elem.find('.number').text(reCount);
        elem.find('.hiddenField').attr('id', 'hiddenField_' + reCount);
        elem.find('.partNumber').attr('id', 'partNumber_' + reCount);
        elem.find('.description').attr('id', 'description_' + reCount);
        elem.find('.price').attr('id', 'price_' + reCount);            
        reCount++;
    });
    count = reCount-1;
};

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    console.log('removed');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    reorder();
});
```

**EDIT** demo starting from 5: https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/25/

Comment: I want the number get from `last().val()`. You may refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/22/)

Comment: so you dont actually want to reorder anything? cause that solution just increments.  is it that you want it to start from 5 and not from 1?

Comment: I need reorder it, but I need to get the `last().val()` and reorder it instead of just reorder. [see this](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/24/)

Comment: so my solution is fine, it just needs to start from 5 instead of 1 all the time?

Comment: Yes, it needs refer from the last value of `.number` in your example

Comment: @Sollo heres the new demo: https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/25/ (also linked in the edit portion of my answer)

Comment: @Sollo lol you got my answer but you apply this answer you are funny

Comment: @hurricane your solution doesnt contain any reordering functionality that OP raised in his question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to get last input number;

- If you will echo a lot of input with classname **countNumber**

You can use  `count = $( ".countNumber" ).last().val();`

- But if you do this, it is much cheap then your method:

In php:

```
foreach($parts as $part)
{               
   $count++;
}
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"countNumber\" value=\"".$count."\">";
```

In js:

```
count = $( "#countNumber" ).val();
```

- Or you can just set your count in php to script:

In php:

```
echo "<script>count =".$count.";</script>"
```

[Working Example on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/22/)

**Important note:** I suggest you don't use `\"`. You can use `'` seperator without it.

**Important note 2:** I suggest you don't use `var hidden = $('<input></input>');` for append a html element. Just use string `var hidden = '<input></input>';`

Comment: An extra question from your important note, why it shouldn't be used?

Comment: @Sollo And if it is working can you apply my answer?

Comment: @Solle Added note 2 for you.

Comment: I'm still trying your answer, but yet I need to reorder the sequence once a number was removed

Comment: @Sollo If you want  sequence don't use count! You need to define id and you can always use newId = lastId + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your HTML structure, you could solve this using a [CSS `counter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

I used your Fiddle and updated it a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/p8hu7qnh/26/

The magic is in the CSS:

```
.container {
    counter-reset: records; // Define the counter
}

li,
.added-field {
    counter-increment: records; // Increment the counter's value
}

li::before,
.added-field::before {
    content: counter(records); // Render the counter's value
}
```